# What is the purpose of {} in dataweave

Tags: dataweave, mule-esb

I am trying to learn Mule DataWeave 2.0 and not many resources out there beside the mule documentation. any good tutorial you can suggest?
With that said, I have the following question 
what is the purpose of {} after ---
for example

```
%dw 2.0
fun toUpper(aString) = upper(aString)
---
toUpper("hello")
```

returns "HELLO"
But if I put

```
---
{ toUpper("hello") }
```

I get an error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In contrast to most programming languages, `{}` in DataWeave is not used for scoping of code.

Here it's used to mark the beginning/ending of an `Object` (a key/value pair sequence), like in JSON.

So, your code emits an error because it expects a `key` before the `"hello"` string value.

For example:

```
{ "some_key": toUpper("hello") }
```

Comment: So what if I want to have mix key/value pair with func call? something like this 
output application/json
var num = 0
fun toUpper(aString) = upper(aString)

---
toUpper("hello")
{
 num : 5
}